# Firestore web code sample gives invalid argument type

Tags: javascript, firebase, gwt, jsni, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying out the new Firestore by Firebase. When I run the code sample from https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0, I am getting an error.

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
db.collection("cities").add({
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

> Exception caught: (FirebaseError) : Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom Object object

Edit:
Sorry I didnt mention I am using GWT and JSNI, it's working fine without gwt

Comment: From a quick scan your code looks correct, which makes me wonder if some unprintable character was copied from the sample. Can you try typing the JSON object that you pass in, to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: I typed it again, no difference

Comment: Hmmm.... in that case I don't know. Let's hope someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have got the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a cross-window issue: GWT code runs in an iframe; if Firebase is looking for a "bare object", it likely compares the object's constructor, which won't be the expected one if the object crosses the iframe boundary.

Maybe try using a `new $wnd.Object()` instead of `{}` or `new Object()`.

Answer (score 3):

Quick workaround

```
var city: any;
city = Object.assign({}, {
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
});
db.collection("cities").add(city)
```

Comment: but why? why do we have to create a new object

Comment: thanks, @thomas-broyer, it's because of the different envs

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code and it works with me if you have data comes as an **Object** from **angular** **Form** :

```
this.afs.collection("/products").add(Object.assign(product));
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)**

Then you can try this:

```
db.collection("cities").add({
    'name': "Tokyo",
    'country': "Japan"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like GWT is producing some custom object like the error says, so as workaround I am using a non JSNI convert method function to create objects like this

```
function convertObject(data) {
    var obj = {}
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key,index) {
        console.log(key);
        obj[key] = data[key];
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Still just a workaround and would love to know if there is a better solution..